# does envoy queue request if max connection on upstream reach a limit?

Tags: envoyproxy

lets say we deployed envoy with a single upstream server .

and now want envoy to queue request if active http request reached a particular limit , if yes how to do it.

What i understood is that it rejects request after a max connection limit is reached.